# JSON_VALUE selecting different row result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table that contains json string in column.
While i am doing query to select json value using `JSON_VALUE` result not coming as expected for the query.

**Person Table detail:**

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[person](
    [UUID] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Payload] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

**query:**

```
select uuid,createdby as fullname ,
  json_value([Payload], '$.name') as Name
 from person
```

Here issue i m facing like in Name column value selecting from different row and that value not existing in same uuid and in row Payload.

**Sample rows Data using for json path:**

```
[{"UUID":"123","Payload":"{ \"author\": \"abc\", \"name\": \"data:image\/png;base64,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\" }","CreatedBy":"abc"},{"UUID":"456","Payload":"{ \"author\": \"xyz\" }","CreatedBy":"xyz"}]
```

**Current Result:**
[image: currentresult]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: That would be a suprising behavior. Please provide sample data, current and desired results.

Comment: @GMB i have updated question

Answer (score 1):

Per your last update you have provided the following JSON:

```json
[
    {
        "UUID":"123",
        "Payload":"{ \"author\": \"abc\", \"name\": "test" }",
        "CreatedBy":"abc"
    },
    {
        "UUID":"456",
        "Payload":"{ \"author\": \"xyz\" }","CreatedBy":"xyz"
    }
]
```

I have removed base64 because of JSON readability.

Where is the problem, in this JSON there is another object called **Payload** and unfortunately values in this object are stored as a string, not as JSON object. Altough it looks like JSON is not treated as JSON object. This is a problem for SQL Engine and `JSON_VALUE` function.

```
SELECT *, 
       JSON_VALUE(value, '$.UUID'), 
       JSON_VALUE(value, '$.Payload.author'), 
       JSON_VALUE(value, '$.Payload.name'), 
       JSON_VALUE(value, '$.CreatedBy')
FROM (select * 
      from openjson('[{"UUID":"123","Payload":"{ \"author\": \"abc\", \"name\": \"test\" }","CreatedBy":"abc"},{"UUID":"456","Payload":"{ \"author\": \"xyz\" }","CreatedBy":"xyz"}]')) ojson
```

The first query will return you all NULL values when you try to access Payload, but the second query will produce the correct data because `\` and `"` are removed from the object and they are not necessary anymore. Compare these two JSONs used in examples and you will see.

```
SELECT *, 
       JSON_VALUE(value, '$.UUID'), 
       JSON_VALUE(value, '$.Payload.author'), 
       JSON_VALUE(value, '$.Payload.name'), 
       JSON_VALUE(value, '$.CreatedBy')
FROM (select * 
      from openjson('[{"UUID":"123","Payload":{ "author": "abc", "name": "test" },"CreatedBy":"abc"},{"UUID":"456","Payload":{ "author": "xyz" },"CreatedBy":"xyz"}]')) ojson
```

Comment: I am sure not using any LAG or LEAD like that command..

Comment: Try to execute this example on your side and see what data you have. It is exactly the same as your example only a temporary table is used.

Comment: i have updated my question current result...sorry previously added wrong current result actually Name value is not `test` it's `Null` value so i m suspecting like it's taking from other row.

Comment: Did you provide the correct JSON? Because it should not be backslash in the JSON. Please try to execute the code provided in my solution and compare with yours.

Comment: As I said, it cannot be backslash (\\) in JSON, this is incorrect. This is JSON when is converted in string in application, but cannot be stored in the database like this.

If you try example from my answer without these backslahes you will get exactly what you need. Obiviously you have another issues.

Comment: @EminMesic Backslashes is *the* way to escape special characters in JSON, please refer to the [grammar](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

Comment: @GSerg there are no special characters in this JSON as you can see, and even there are \r\n which are representing new row. I have updated my answer on the provided data.

Comment: @EminMesic The "Sample rows Data" is a result of a `for json` query. The json value in Payload is taken in quotes by the outer query so quotes and whitespaces originally found inside it must now be escaped. The value that the OP actually has in the Payload column is `{<newline>    "author":"abc",<newline>    "name":"test"<newline> }`.

Comment: @GSerg you are right this is JSON copied from the application or from some builder, but you have same JSON prepared in my answer for the purpose of the query and it produces results correctly.

Comment: @EminMesic again i have updated question after tested with your provided example and actual json copied from db using for json path...but current result is not expected result it's returning null in name.

Comment: @r08 answer is updated, please take a look.

Comment: @EminMesic eventhough no `\' and `"` returning null.

Comment: What is difference between your JSON and second example in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

...check that the payload string has a json key = "name" and no invisible/non-printable characters have crept in there:

```
declare @t table(id int identity, payload nvarchar(max));
insert into @t(payload)
values
(N'{"author": "abc", "name": "data:image..png;base64"}'),
(N'{"author": "abc", "na'+ nchar(8299) +N'me": "data:image..png;base64"}');

select *, isjson(payload) as payloadisjson
from @t;

select *, 'payload like %name%'
from @t
where payload like N'%name%';    

select *, json_value(payload, '$.name') as jsonvalue_name, '??'
from @t;

select *, json_value(payload, N'$.name') as jsonvalue_name,  'json key is not N''name''', 
cast(op.[key] as varbinary(20)) as keybin, cast(N'name' as varbinary(20)) keyshouldbebin
from @t as t
cross apply openjson(payload) as op
where op.[key] like '%n%e%'
and cast(op.[key] as varbinary(20)) <> cast(N'name' as varbinary(20));
```